# How to require a file with a dot in the name?

Tags: lua

I am trying to require `"config/lsp.rc.lua"`, but doing `require("config.lsp.rc")` gives an error.

Comment: Why didn't you do `require("config/lsp.rc.lua")`?

Comment: @TimRoberts because that also errors

Comment: What error?  It should accept an arbitrary file path.  Assuming the directory that contains "config" is in your lua path, it will work.

Comment: @TimRoberts `config/lsp.rc.lua` points to `config/lsp/rc.lua` instead

Comment: Well, then, use `"config/lsp/rc.lua"`.

Comment: the file is called "lsp.rc.lua"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is simple: The responsible `require` loader will replace each dot with the directory separator (`/` on Unix).

Note that you should *not* use `/` in `require` since it is a platform-specific directory separator (in practice it will be supported by Windows though).

Your best option would be to simply rename the file, replacing the dot with an underscore or the like to abide by Lua's conventions here.

However, if this is out of your control, you may also monkey-patch `require` to support your use case.

Instead of using `.` as directory separator, we may use `/`.

For that, we have to implement our own searcher:

> Each entry in this table is a searcher function. When looking for a module, require calls each of these searchers in ascending order, with the module name (the argument given to require) as its sole argument. If the searcher finds the module, it returns another function, the module loader, plus an extra value, a loader data, that will be passed to that loader and returned as a second result by require. If it cannot find the module, it returns a string explaining why (or nil if it has nothing to say).

Luckily we can leverage [`package.searchpath`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-package.searchpath) to do most of the work for us:

```lua
local function searcher(module_name)
    -- Use "/" instead of "." as directory separator
    local path, err = package.searchpath(module_name, package.path, "/")
    if path then
        return assert(loadfile(path))
    end
    return err
end
```

Now we just have to pluck this into [`package.searchers`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-package.searchers) for `require` to use it. We could insert it first, last, wherever, doesn't matter, so let's insert it last, such that *only* if all builtin searchers fail our searcher is tried:

```lua
table.insert(package.searchers, searcher)
```

Usage:

```lua
local lsp_rc = require("config/lsp.rc")
```

will then work as expected.

If you do not want to globally patch `require`, you could implement a local `require` that just searches in the Lua path, using your conventions:

```lua
local function myrequire(module_name)
    return assert(loadfile(assert(package.searchpath(module_name, package.path, "/"))))
end
local lsp_rc = myrequire("config/lsp.rc")
```